# Web fonts and HTML5 Application cache feature in WPF WebView control (Metro)

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm creating a metro application using C# and WPF.

I want to include a WebView for showing some web content. But the problem is, Some HTML5/CSS3 Features are not available in WebView, while they are available in IE10.

For example, WebView is not showing Web fonts, but IE10 does.

Also, [html5test](http://html5test.com) says that WebView does not support application cache (and some other features), while IE10 also supports application cache.

How to implement Web fonts and HTML5 Application cache in WPF WebView Control?

Answer (score 1):

Think in WebView as a simple way to view web content. Sadly the WebView control is not a full featured IE10 and hence, it lacks of some functionality. I suggest you to simplify the input if you control webpage, or rethink the application features :(